# Wrapping text around image in memoir document class

Tags: graphics, memoir, wrap

I am using the memoir document class and I want to wrap text around an image. The image should be on the left and the text beside it. This is my main syntax:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage[inner=3cm,outer=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{palatino}
\setlength{\parindent}{4em}
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
\usepackage{picinpar}
\makechapterstyle{custom}{%
\chapterstyle{default}
\def\chapterheadstart{}
}   
\chapterstyle{custom}
```

For this image:

```
\newline
\begin{wrapfigure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{image.png} 
\end{wrapfigure}
```

I have tried to import the wrapfig package, but it produces errors for the whole document. Is there another way to simply wrap the text around?

Thanks!

Comment: There is also the picins package, \hangindent, \parshape and \leftskip.  It sort of depends on how many paragraphs and where the transitions occur.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I don't see why it should, except perhaps a conflict with the very old (latex 2.09!) package `picinpar`, which you load. Could post a full code demonstrating the problem?

Comment: I'll add to @John Kormylo's list `cutwin` and the easy-to-use plain TeX set of macros `insbox`.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I have heard of \parshape, is there any syntax on how to use it?

Comment: And I only have around 4 sentences that need to be wrapped, so should fit around the fairly small image. Which would be recommended in light of this?

Comment: For four sentences, \hangindent is easier.  It's a plain TeX macro which can provide indentation at the start or end of a paragraph for either the left or right sides (in combination with \hangafter).  The only thing it can't do is more than one indentation per paragraph, or affect more than one paragraph (at a time).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a demonstration for `\hangindent` for 4 lines.  I deliberately started the image at the baseline and used an image smaller than the gap.

Note that wrapfigure normally adds a full `\baselineskip` above and below the image.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage[inner=3cm,outer=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{palatino}
\setlength{\parindent}{4em}
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
\usepackage{picinpar}
\makechapterstyle{custom}{%
\chapterstyle{default}
\def\chapterheadstart{}
}   
\chapterstyle{custom}
\usepackage{lipsum}% generic text
\usepackage{wrapfig}% required for wrapfigure

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\sbox0{\includegraphics[height=2.5\baselineskip]{example-image}}% measure image
\rlap{\raisebox{-\ht0}[0pt][0pt]{\usebox0}}\vspace{-\baselineskip}% overlay image
\hangindent=\dimexpr \wd0+\columnsep\relax
\hangafter=-4
\lipsum[2]
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0pt}
\usebox0
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thank you. In your code, where would I actually put my text? My syntax:  '\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{image}
\textbf{Header} This is a sentence I was using....'

Comment: Just replace \lipsum with the paragraph desired.

Comment: That hasn't worked... the image became too small and actually created two small images.

Comment: You don't HAVE to use [height=2.5\baselineskip].  i did that to make the image fit in 4 lines of text.

Comment: Same OP, asked one day earlier. Duplicate? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319341/wrapping-text-next-to-image

Comment: No. I need your expertise. Is that other question a duplicate of this one here? If not, can it be answered or should it be (considering the time it is laying around unnoticed) be closed? Or is there room for improvement?

Comment: @Johannes_B - I would close it either as a duplicate or unclear (no MWE).  Presumably he asked this question instead of editing his original to add a MWE.