# Wrapping text next to image

Tags: graphics, wrap, text

I have issues displaying three images with wrapfig. The first two are formatted fine, but, for the third, the text comes beneath the image instead of to the side. After the image and its accompanying text, there is another new paragraph that I would like to be separate from the third image, this may be interfering with the format of the third image too. Could someone please suggest a way to fix this? Code and image below.

Thank you!

[image]

```
\newline
\newline\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.2\textwidth} \vspace{-20pt}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{image1}
  \end{center}
  \vspace{-20pt}
  \vspace{1pt}
\end{wrapfigure} 
\textbf{fgdov} has gfd undgfduate gs, and is completing a Mastfdgfdgfdgfders degree in Bioinformatics at KU.  Her thesis igfdgfdnership with gty and will   fdgfd work on the rgent of our ideafdgfd, ag ighfde effects ofdgdf n different fgta. Shefd presentlfdgfdy works in g at the microbiome fdgfd gfdgfdangcompanfdy fdgfd gdfgfdg gdfgfdg dgfd gof the latest gfdge fgfdg gfdg gfdg gfd h of kge in this fiefdg  gfdgfdld.
\bigbreak
\newline \begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.2\textwidth}
\vspace{-20pt}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{image2}
 \end{center}
 \vspace{-20pt}
 \vspace{1pt}
 \end{wrapfigure}\noindent \textbf{Mul Ltyargo} has uyt for su ytuytnths in a pharmaceutical microbiology lab as part of his phuytcy buytlor. Curu he iyts stuytng a combined Master inuyt andytuU in yutess Adyttion and Biouytuhip. Heyt is working at the same time in a consultant company specialized in new heauyt prtyucts uyt the market. Therefore,ueyt tu tot apply the yuntyturepuiytp theories toytety practicauytes of our start up, gutiu thyte buss eytdge.\bigbreak
\newline
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.2\textwidth}
\vspace{-70pt}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{image3}
  \end{center}
  \vspace{-10pt}
  \vspace{1pt}
\end{wrapfigure} \textbf{uytoffer Husyttad} fsd a bacuytound in micrytogy aytd fytod sytnce, comfging the nedfdssssary mifdlogy knowledge nyutd to adus oytur bufsess. ute huyts a  backfgdnd from the ffustry,sdfds and experuytynce from resfdsrch in nfdsrition. Dufg dshis bflordss, he dsfd a project on fsdfdstion,  specifically on how nutfdstion afftsds athletes.
\bigbreak
\newline
\newline \textbf {BOARD} fdfds dsfds fdsfds dsgdsgsdg dssfdsfds
\newline
\begin{itemize}
```

Comment: What about a compilable MWE which does demonstrate your problem?